# How to copy paste between Android and Windows?

Tags: windows, copy-paste

I just want Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V work across all devices: from Windows to Android and from Android to Windows. Be it just a text or a file ([like this in pushbullet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xGb7MU-eg9k), but for pushbullet, universal copy paste is premium feature.)

I am trying AirDroid. What all I found related to this is this:
[image: screenshot of AirDroid user interface]

I have to do Ctrl+C, then open this app, go to relevant device tab and click these buttons.

**Q1.** Is this the procedure? Can't I just do Ctrl+C on Windows and long press and paste on Android. Also copying from Android's clipboard to Windows did not work while the other way worked every time.

**Q2.** Is there another way? Is there any better software which does it for free, for text and files, without lag, on same network devices?

Comment: Telegram or Whatsapp Web will also work for sending text and files to your computer or vice versa (if you have a phone number).

Answer (score 0):

I personally use MyPhoneExplorer. It is a free software without any ads or malware. Actually it is a full fledged PC suite for Android. It supports universal clipboard, screen mirroring & many other things.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung SideSync is good software. You  just need to drag and drop from android to windows computer. Operating system require is Windows XP Service Pack 3 and higher.